# LyX display size is small for me

Tags: lyx, fontsize, size

I'm visually impaired and I find it really hard to use the settings themselves, I'm using the windows magnifier to navigate but can't find the option to increase the setting font size. I want the font of the settings itself to be bigger does anyone know if there's an option to do so?
I found the option to increase the icon size but not the ui font size

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The basic font sizes available with standard classes are 10pt, 11pt and 12pt (default is 10pt), but with the `extsizes`  package, you also can choose `14, 17 or 20 pt`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, How do I implement the changes exactly, and where do I choose the font sizes?

Comment: The font size is set as an option of the \document class (for the basic sizes: 10,11 or 12pt). For `extsizes`, you can write, for instance , `\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}` (or `extreport`, &c.)

Comment: Do I need to write it as a program in miktex? I"m using LyX and I haven't studied programming yet if  that's what you're referring to, I thought there'd be an option in the settings somewhere maybe?

Comment: You only have to modify the underlying LaTeX preamble. I don't use LyX, but I believe it is accessible.

Comment: oh.. I don't know where to find it

Comment: Maybe ask another question, and a LyX user will be able to answer?

Comment: To change the font size in scren text , just Ctrl+mouse whell of Help>Preferences>lok&Fell>Screen Font. The font of menus and dialog windows AFAIK depends on the OS settings only. The outupt font of the PDF is that Bernardo commented and can be set in Document > Setting > Document Class > Class Options

Comment: Fran, my OS settings for the font size is bigger than what the LyX size is currently so it doesn't seem like they're connected, and I got to the font Size but it's for the writing in the document and not the settings, what are you thinking?

Comment: Might Try that Bernard thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the [lyx wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Fonts) states, "Menu and dialogs font is not part of LyX preferences - you must change your Qt settings - on linux platforms qtconfig is your friend.".

You can [ask the developers](https://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki) to make this as a preference option, that way it might be possible in lyx 2.4